# CSS - Changing style in a specific area in html

Tags: css

I'm new to css. How do I change a specific area in the html tag? I don't want to change all `<li>` elements. I just want to change `<li> item1_content2 </li>`.

Is this how you do it in **css**?

```
.content2 li {
   /* some properties*/
}
```

---

```
<div class="content1">
<ul>
   <li>item1_content1</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="content2">
<ul>
   <li>item1_content2</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @Kroltan http://w3fools.com/...

Comment: wrap your content inside h1, h2, h3 or p tags

Comment: @Kolink Well it's the only place I found that provides nice functional examples.

Comment: "nice" and "functional" mean nothing when half of them are wrong. Try MDN instead.

Comment: I know right. The explanations are ridiculous.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example yes, this is the way. Generally you can do many things like assign an id or class, use child selectors or pseudo selectors. It's up to you!